# How to assign assign type in a generic class with a param java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java, generics

If I have a class with a generic like this:

```
public class ResponseSimple<T> {

    private Map<String, Collection<String>> headers;
    private int status;
    private T body;
}
```

Then,in other class I have a method which I need to use an instance of this class, but the method passes by param a java.lang.reflect.Type and it's overrided so I can't change the any of the method (name, signature..):

```
public class ResponseEncoder extends GsonDecoder {

    public ResponseEncoder() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException
    {
        //How assign type T using type param??
        //¿ResponseSimple<T> responseSimple = new ResponseSimple();?

        return null;
    }

}
```

How could I assign the generic type T using the param type (java.lang.reflect.Type)?

Comment: You have two separate `response` variables of different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
@Override
public <T> T decode(Response response, Class<T> type) throws IOException
{
    //How assign type T using type param??
    ResponseSimple<T> response = new ResponseSimple<T>();

    return response;
}
```

Then use decode as follows:

```
.decode(response, NameOfClass.class)
```

Edit:

If you need to extend your class you could use a static helper function:

```
public static <T> ResponseSimple<T> createResponse(Class<T> clazz)
{
       return new ResponseSimple<>();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class ResponseEncoder extends GsonDecoder {

    public ResponseEncoder() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException
    {
        Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type; 
        ResponseSimple<?> response = createResonse(clazz); 

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm extending a class so this method  it's overrided and I can't change it :( It must be java.lang.reflect.Type

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't works :( Error: The method createResponse(Class<T>) in the type ResponseSimple is not applicable for the arguments (Type)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly.
To create a new instance of your generic class you need to infer the correct type arguments like this if you want your `ResponseSimple<T>` to contain `java.lang.reflect.Type`:

```
ResponseSimple<Type> response = new ResponseSimple<>();
```

So, inbetween the `<>` you need to add the name of the class you want to use.

Also have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

//EDIT:
As you said you want to infer the type arguments dynamically, what you did works fine for me. The only thing is that you forgot the diamond operator:

```
@Override
public Object decode(Response response, T type) throws IOException
{
   ResponseSimple<T> response = new ResponseSimple<>(); //<> in the second part

   return null;
 }
```

Comment: I wanted to use the type which it's passed by param with the param type not the class Type, thanks!

Comment: Then just replace `<Type>` with `<ClassName>`

Comment: But I can't I get the type ClassName by type param and I need to put it dynamically

Comment: Okay, I see. Actually, this works perfectly fine for me. What Java Version are you using?